# Session timeout based on community/group with Liferay

Tags: java, session, liferay, liferay-6

I need to customize the Liferay 6.0.5 behavior regarding the session timeout.
I have 3 community on the same Liferay instance, 2 extranets and an intranet
I wish to define a custom timeout for a specific community (on the intranet : no timeout).

I've checked out the session_timeout.jspf file and the session.js script but i can't see how customize it in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also take a look at the /ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml, the following part:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Also in portal-ext.properties:

`session.timeout=30`
`session.timeout.warning=1`
`session.timeout.auto.extend=false`
`session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true`

For a custom handler I would try to modify the `\liferay-portal-6.0.5\tomcat-6.0.26\webapps\ROOT\html\common\themes\session_timeout.jspf`:

Something like this:

```
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="<%= themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getName().equals("MyCustomCommunity_1") %>">
        <aui:script use="liferay-session">
            Liferay.Session.init(
              {
                autoExtend: false /*my custom value*/,
                timeout: 5 /*my custom value*/,
                timeoutWarning: 0 /*my custom value*/,
                redirectOnExpire: '/web/guest/mycustompage1' /*my custom value*/
              }
            );
        </aui:script>
      </c:when>
      <c:when test="<%= themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getName().equals("MyCustomCommunity_2") %>">
        <aui:script use="liferay-session">
            Liferay.Session.init(
              {
                autoExtend: true /*my custom value*/,
                timeout: 15 /*my custom value*/,
                timeoutWarning: 1 /*my custom value*/,
                redirectOnExpire: '/web/guest/mycustompage2' /*my custom value*/
              }
            );
        </aui:script>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <aui:script use="liferay-session">
          Liferay.Session.init(
            {
              autoExtend: <%= PropsValues.SESSION_TIMEOUT_AUTO_EXTEND %>,
              timeout: <%= sessionTimeout %>,
              timeoutWarning: <%= sessionTimeoutWarning %>,
              redirectOnExpire: <%= PropsValues.SESSION_TIMEOUT_REDIRECT_ON_EXPIRE %>
            }
          );
        </aui:script>
      </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Comment: ok but the same configuration will be applied for my 3 communities, i want 2 different configuration regarding the community

Comment: I've updated the code with a possible solution to set your own custom session timeout handler, based on name of the current group.

Answer (score 0):

will the

```
redirectOnExpire: '/web/guest/mycustompage1' /*my custom value*/
```

redirect to the specified url, if a user clicks on any of the links or buttons on the page or will it be automatically redirected after  the session timeout. In my liferay application, we have several widgets hosted on dashboard page, when a user clicks on any widget it opens a new tab and the widget related info is displayed. When the session times out the widget is opened in new tab but the page is redirected to /web/guest/home , that is the desired behavior. however  the dashboard page still remains as the page is not automatically redirected to /web/guest/home after session timeout. how to make the dashboard page redirect to /web/guest/home after session timeout automatically.